# press and hold mouse event in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, onclick

I have a below button in LWC

HTML:

```
    <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:chevronright" 
onmousedown={slideRight} variant="bare">
```

JS:

```
slideRight() {
        this.template.querySelector('[data-id="container"]').scrollLeft += 100;
    }
```

It's purpose is to slide the page horizontally and it is working as expected but the problem is it works only on single click doesn't keep sliding on press and hold I have tried **onmousedown**, **onmouseup** but still no luck, could someone please suggest any work around for the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onmousedown` and `onmouseup` only trigger when a button is pressed or released, respectively. Unlike some keyboard events, they do not repeat periodically. It is therefore up to you to determine when/how to repeat. Here is a sample [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/mp3gopKt/1/edit) for you to look at. The code for this is below.

---

```
<template>
    <lightning-button label="Increase Counter" onmousedown={increaseCounter} onmouseup={stopCounting}></lightning-button>
    <hr></hr>
    <input readonly value={counter}></input>

</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track counter = 0;
    timerId;
    increaseCounter() {
        this.counter++;
        this.timerId = setTimeout(this.increaseCounter.bind(this), 100);
    }
    stopCounting() {
        clearTimeout(this.timerId);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good stuff, I was able to break it fairly easily by holding down the click, moving my mouse out of the button and letting go. After that it didn't matter how many times I clicked on the button, the counter never stopped. I don't think it necessarily takes away from your answer though, more that it shows the limitations of the pattern.

Comment: @gNerb It's not a "fully functional" demo, you'd also want to track `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` and figure out if the mouse was pressed or not using the MouseEvent button attributes. I wasn't going for complicated, I was going for minimalistic.